# How does Academy Manufactor apply to creature tokens of its listed types?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What happens if I have [Academy Manufactor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Academy%20Manufactor) out and I cast [Cackling Counterpart](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cackling%20Counterpart) targeting my own [Parcel Myr](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Parcel%20Myr), [Goldhound](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Goldhound), or [Gingerbrute](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gingerbrute)?

A ruling on Parcel Myr states

> (...) Abilities that care about creating a Clue token, such as that of Academy Manufactor, will do nothing as Parcel Myr is put onto the battlefield. If you create a token that's a copy of Parcel Myr on the battlefield, such abilities will notice. (...)

But that doesn't explain whether the replacement effect will change the copy of Parcel Myr into a noncreature Clue. Do I create a token that's a copy of Parcel Myr plus a Food token and a Treasure token, or ordinary noncreature Clue, Food, and Treasure tokens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Academy Manufactor's replacement effect applies to creating a token copy of any of those creatures being created, and instead of getting a copy of that creature, you will create a Clue, a Food, and a Treasure token each, none of which being any more than the basic version of that token.**

Academy Manufactor's ability is a replacement effect, which roughly means "if something would happen, it doesn't happen, and something else happens instead".
This really is a better explanation than any rules quote would give in my opinion, however if you want to read further, there's [this excellent page on magicjudges.org](https://blogs.magicjudges.org/ftw/l2-prep/rules-and-policy/replacement-effects/) on the topic, and of course for completeness's sake, a relevant rules quote:

> **614.6.** If an event is replaced, it never happens. A modified event occurs instead, which may in turn trigger abilities.

Two conditions need to be true for the same permanent in order for Academy Manufactor's ability to apply:

- the permanent needs to be a token
- the permanent needs to have the Clue, Food, or Treasure artifact type

Both happen to be true for the creatures mentioned, so this perhaps unusual interaction happens.

Comment: The key here is that there are two things which could be called "Clue tokens".  One is a token with the artifact type "Clue", and the other is a token defined by rule 111.10f, which has the name "Clue", the type "Clue", and the activated ability.  The replacement action looks for the former, and replaces it with the latter (and also a food and a treasure).  Yes, this is kind of weird.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus less wierdly, the former is a generalisation of the latter. Manufactor sees anything of the general kind, and replaces it with the specific kind. In the normal case, you are replacing an 111.10f clue with an indistinguishable 111.10f clue, so it's easy to miss the replacement