Does Academy Manufactor's ability trigger on creatures that "are Food artifacts in addition to their other types"?
If Academy Manufactor and Ygra, Eater of All are both on the field and a creature is played, would that creature also trigger the ability of Academy Manufactor, since it is technically a food?
Or would it not, for a reason like the creature not having the additional typing until after it all resolves?
Academy Manufactor's ability being:

If you would create a Clue, Food, or Treasure token, instead create one of each.

and Ygra, Eater of All's being:

Ward—Sacrifice a Food.
Other creatures are Food artifacts in addition to their other types
and have “{2}, {T}, Sacrifice this permanent: You gain 3 life.”
Whenever a Food is put into a graveyard from the battlefield, put
two +1/+1 counters on Ygra, Eater of All.


Relevant: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/57620/how-does-academy-manufactor-apply-to-creature-tokens-of-its-listed-types

No, there is no interaction between Academy Manufactor and Ygra.
First, I want to note that Academy Manufactor specifically affects creating tokens, so it never affects playing a permanent card, even if that card inherently has one of the specified types, such as Candy Trail.
With that being said, Academy Manufactor also does not affect the creation of creature tokens while you control Ygra. Academy Manufactor's ability is a replacement effect, and replacement effects do not generally take into account what the board state will/would be like after the modified effect resolves.

As an exception to the previous statement, some replacement effects, called "enters the battlefield" replacement effects, do look ahead to continuous effects that will affect a permanent after the modified event resolves, and replacement effects like that would take Ygra's ability into account. These are described in rule 614.12:

614.12. Some replacement effects modify how a permanent enters the battlefield. (See rules 614.1c–d.) Such effects may come from the permanent itself if they affect only that permanent (as opposed to a general subset of permanents that includes it). They may also come from other sources. To determine which replacement effects apply and how they apply, check the characteristics of the permanent as it would exist on the battlefield, taking into account replacement effects that have already modified how it enters the battlefield (see rule 616.1), continuous effects from the permanent’s own static abilities that would apply to it once it’s on the battlefield, and continuous effects that already exist and would apply to the permanent.

The referenced rules 614.1c-d describe which wordings of replacement effects qualify as "enters the battlefield" replacement effects:

614.1c Effects that read “[This permanent] enters the battlefield with . . . ,” “As [this permanent] enters the battlefield . . . ,” or “[This permanent] enters the battlefield as . . . “ are replacement effects.
614.1d Continuous effects that read “[This permanent] enters the battlefield . . .” or “[Objects] enter the battlefield . . .” are replacement effects.

As you can see, none of those match Academy Manufactor's ability, so that exception does not apply to Academy Manufactor.

Why does this work when creating a token copy of Gingerbrute but not a token copy of Grizzly Bears with Yrga in play?

Because Gingerbrute is printed with the type Food and Grizzly Bears is not. The effect of Ygra's ability that gives Grizzly Bears the Food type does not affect the Grizzly Bears' copyable attributes, so you only consider Grizzly Bears base characteristics when determining whether to apply the replacement effect.

"o determine which replacement effects apply and how they apply, check the characteristics of the permanent as it would exist on the battlefield, taking into account replacement effects that have already modified how it enters the battlefield (see rule 616.1), continuous effects from the permanent's own static abilities that would apply to it once it's on the battlefield, and continuous effects that already exist and would apply to the permanent. "?

"Academy Manufactor" replacement effect explicitly pays attention to " continuous effects that already exist and would apply to the permanent".  You create a Bear Token.  By Ygra, that bear token will (continuously) be a Food.  As a Food and a Token, instead of creating a Bear (Food) Token, you should instead create a Food, Clue and Treasure token.  The question is, does a Bear Token that is a Food count as a Food Token?

"Academy Manufactor replacement effect explicitly pays attention to continuous effects that already exist and would apply to the permanent". I already addressed that in my answer: no it doesn't. It's not an "enters the battlefield" replacement effect. Rule 614.1c-d describes the templating of abilities that count as "enters the battlefield" replacement effects, and Academy Manufactor's ability does not match those.

I didn't believe you were correct, so I tested this in Arena using Yrga and Worldwalker Helm (since Academy Manufactor is not in Arena), and it worked (or rather, didn't work) exactly as you described.
